# setup SSL on AppEngine... Assigned URLs "empty"

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl

I have setup Custom Domain "https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain"

I have uploaded "An SSL certificate and private key"  (to create those i am using "XCA" on Ubuntu, available in the Ubuntu Software Center" )

Result ..."Assign all matching URLs" or "Add" Button is inactive.

What are the details to follow setting up SSL for AppEgine Custom Domain?

HELP: following the link on "http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2644386" refers to a login see: (moma single sign on) ???->

https://login.corp.google.com/saml_idp?KeyID=w1n&SAMLRequest=fVJNT%2BMwEL0j7X%2BwfM8nYoWsJqgLQluJhYgGDtwcZ1KctT3B47Tw70lTEN3DcvTz8%2FsYz%2BLi1Rq2BU8aXcGzOOUMnMJWu03BH%2Brr6JxflD9OFiStGcRyDM%2FuHl5GoMCml47EfFHw0TuBkjQJJy2QCEqsl39uRB6nYvAYUKHhbHVV8N4hdoPq26a1%2FeYvmB6taXXTY9%2FIRjfN4IbOSsXZ42esfB9rRTTCylGQLkxQmuVR%2BjPKz%2BvsVJzm4ix94qz6cPql3aHBd7GaA4nE77quoupuXc8CW92Cv53YBd8gbgzECu3evpJEejvBnTQEnC2JwIcp4CU6Gi34NfitVvBwf1Pw5xAGEkmy2%2B3iL5lEJscHRbycJyvmcv5opN9Hl5%2FWvPzSWyRHUuXHj%2B2LrK4qNFq9saUxuLv0IMPUIvhxKnGN3srwf7cszmZEt1E3U8XoaAClOw0tZ0l5cP13NaaFeQc%3D&RelayState=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fa%2Fgoogle.com%2FServiceLogin%3Fservice%3Dah%26passive%3Dtrue%26continue%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fappengine.google.com%252F_ah%252Fconflogin%253Fcontinue%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fdevsite.googleplex.com%252Fappengine%252Fdocs%252Fssl%26ltmpl%3Dga%26shdf%3DCioLEgZhaG5hbWUaHkdvb2dsZSBEZXZTaXRlIENvbnRlbnQgU3RhZ2luZwwSAmFoIhRMUzrDPeZIM0WftD9x6Ag2ike0YCgBMhQmSRWl793zR9on0qxjQb8iedMy3Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple the domain i am using should use CN -> **www.abc.com** and not just **abc.com**.

"All subject names on the host certificate should match or be subdomains of the domains associated with the account in the Google Apps Control Panel."

Thank's for the documentation link :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct documentation link:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl

Answer (score 1):

when adding an app engine app to use SSL over your custom domain. Create the PEM encoded X.509 certificate and Unencrypted PEM encoded RSA private key with openssl:

```
openssl genrsa -out rsaprivkey.pem 1024

openssl req -new -x509 -key rsaprivkey.pem -out dsacert.pem
```

when open ssl asks you questions for your app's name, make sure to include the entire url as in your answer, www.abc.com to secure https://www.abc.com

-Ben

Answer (score 0):

Under Google App Admin console -> select App Engine apps -> select app -> Add New URL