# SSL google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, google-apps

In order to enable SSL in Appengine.
I try to enable SSL for my custom domain

So far I found this article:

[setup SSL on AppEngine... Assigned URLs "empty"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245876/setup-ssl-on-appengine-assigned-urls-empty)

```
openssl genrsa -out rsaprivkey.pem 1024
openssl req -new -x509 -key rsaprivkey.pem -out dsacert.pem
```

then I uploaded the generated `.pem` to `google app` SSL setting page

```
dsacert.pem > PEM encoded X.509 certificate 
rsaprivkey.pem > Unencrypted PEM encoded RSA private key
```

However, I got this error message after Upload.
What should I do next?

> Domain name in certificate should only contain allowed characters (RFC
>   1034).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve!

It this article
[setup SSL on AppEngine... Assigned URLs "empty"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245876/setup-ssl-on-appengine-assigned-urls-empty)

> when open ssl asks you questions for your app's name, make sure to
>   include the entire url as in your answer, www.abc.com to secure
>   https://www.abc.com

But I didn't find any place to enter my app's name during the openssl pem generation at first.

finally I find out the domain should be filled in organization and common name fields.
http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/generate-a-csr-with-openssl

```
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]: > example.com
Common Name (eg, YOUR name) > *.example.com
```